# issue opening document using FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION intent ANDROID

Tags: android

I would like to open my documents saved in application storage using third party applications like polaris office,quickoffice,kingsoft docs etc using chooser.I would like to grant permission to edit the document as well.

If i open the document using FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION,the document opens fine but if i use FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION  insted the external application pushedup but donot display the document selected.Incase of polaris office,the document opens fine using FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION but if i use FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION   it says document type not supported.

The code i use is

```
    File file = new File(
            getFilePath(data.getUniqueId(), data.getFileName()));
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.com",
            file);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION); 
    Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(intent, uri.toString());
    context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

In manifest i have mentioned

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.com"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/my_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Please let me know where i am wrong.

I would like to provide temporary permission to third part apps to open and edit the document selected.The documents need to be stored in application storage space.

Answer (score 1):

instead of the line:

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

just put the line:

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION 
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I think your provider should also have `android:exported` attribute set to `true` (in order to be used by other applications).

Comment: `android:exported` must be false. `FileProvider` enforces this additional restriction though in general it's not required URI granting to work.